# USB Wi-Fi adapter doesn’t wakeup on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, usb, wireless-networking, standby

I'm using the Linksys WUSB300N USB Wi-Fi adapter under Windows Vista Home Premium x64.
The problem is it doesn't wakeup when computer goes out of standby. It's really annoying.

I have 1.0.3.2 version of drivers dated 2007-09-11, and I think they are the newest ones.

In the network adapters/Wireless-N USB Network Adapter/Properties/Power Management I have "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" unchecked and "Allow this device to wake the computer" is inactive (disabled).

I have a couple of other USB devices and there is no problem with them after the computer wakes up.

Comment: Has anyone accomplished this wirelessly ?

Comment: @flashkube Yep, could be a company laptop. Edit to read Vista Business Premium and question suddenly becomes legit.

Answer (score 3):

First thing to check is that the computer is not set to turn it off to save power:

- Open device manager
- Expand Network Adapters, right-click your Linksys Wireless device, and then click Properties.
- Click the Power Management tab.
- The Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power check box is displayed, make sure it is unchecked.

Comment: This has been the fix for me with multiple XP systems.

Comment: Thought the same and unchecked it some time ago. No change.

Answer (score 2):

The drivers are the newest ones, and it is an issue that will probably never be fixed by Linksys. The only solution I have found can be found in *[A USB device may no longer work correctly after Windows Vista resumes from sleep or from hibernation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928631/)*.

Follow the instructions starting from the **Post-installation instructions** section.

Comment: Nice link, thanks. Did what was prescribed but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [Vista SP2](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1137482/vista-service-pack-light) might be of use to you

*"Microsoft says that the Service Pack will also bring... improved Wi-Fi performance when resuming from Sleep mode*

Comment: I do like the 'improved performance' meaning it works at all.   Perhaps I should try that, improved execution lifetime = it doesn't immediately crash

Comment: I installed SP2 and this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the Advanced Power Options.  Vista can be set to turn off the USB ports to save power.

Since your WiFi device is USB-based, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in your BIOS settings to see if there are any options for USB settings?  Also, have you tried something else like a USB hard drive to see if that spins back up after waking the computer from sleep?  That may help see if the problem is with the adapter or the port.

Lastly, I'd move the adapter to another machine to see if it does the same thing (ideally one using XP or a different OS than you're currently using).

Comment: I have a couple of other USB devices and there is no problem with them after the computer wakes up.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with intel network cards. My work around was to run a batch file when you wake the PC up.

If you want to do it this way, the utility you need is [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272). You then use this in a .bat file using the restart argument and then name of the device which you can find using the findall argument.

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows *[Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager)*, I would check to see if the USB Wi-Fi adapter has any power-related settings in its hardware configuration. I know that I've remedied various wakeup issues with Wi-Fi cards and Windows Vista by adjusting their settings within the Device Manager (but never a USB adapter, so this is a bit of a crapshoot).

Comment: In the network adapters/Wireless-N USB Network Adapter/Properties/Power Management I have "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" unchecked and "Allow this device to wake the computer" is inactive (disabled).

Comment: And those settings were like that by default?

Comment: No, I changed them. I don't remember default values, however.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista, I had some troubles with the Wi-Fi startup until I add the following script at startup.

```
net stop Wlansvc
net start Wlansvc
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue with Wi-Fi cards and many USB devices. The latest drivers and playing with your power saving settings are the way to go. Stopping and restarting the device has given me some success, but it is hit and miss.

Answer (score -1):

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/search.aspx?q=wusb300n

You obvously do not get any advantage of using non-HCL (never tested at microsoft) driver even with newer version number. Thus try one offered as part of windows HCL

Comment: The site shows version 1.0.0.4 from 2007-01-19 which is older than what I describe in my question.